# Reading and Writing to Excel sheet in C# UWP Windows 10 App

Tags: c#, excel, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on a project for Windows 10 UWP App. **I have below two problems**

**1.** **I have to upload excel sheet containing the data, and store that
    data into Sq-lite Database.**

**2.** **Also I have to read data from database table, and write to excel sheet in
    rows and column format.**

I have searched a lot but could not find **any library or helping blog**. I would be thankful for any complete guide or sample code. Thanks!!

Comment: You can use my free C# library to easily export data to Excel.  Source code is provided..
www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

Comment: Convert excel csv

Comment: Can you please guide me about how can i use your library in my windows 10 UWP app. I have to read and write data to excel file in my UWP Windows 10 app. Thanks  @MikeGledhill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use [**Syncfusion Essential XlsIO**](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio). It does the work for your read/write of excel files (also works with Xamarin and ASP.Net). It has a 30-day free trial but you can get a free community license.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, thx to .Net Standard 2.0 we are able to use the OpenXML SDK! This allows you to create and/or manipulate MS Office documents.

As an example I've blogged about creating Excel files on the fly in Xamarin Forms ( that also can generate an UWP app ) here http://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/10/13/net-standard-2-0-create-microsoft-office-documents-in-xamarin-forms/

The SDK itself is open source https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK and there is a very large detailed documentation site available too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx