# Is Syncfusion.XLSIO library for windows 10 UWP is a free or paid one?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, uwp, syncfusion

I wanted to know whether Syncfusion library for reading and writing excel files in windows UWP is free or a paid one ? I have implemented it by using Syncfusion.xlsio library in visual studio 2015 which supports reading and writing excel sheet in windows UWP. But somewhere I read in the below link that its a  paid one, the trial version works only for 30 days. I did not see any word regarding money when I downloaded through Nuget packager . Please confirm me if anyone here knows about it.
**Link:**
[Reading and Writing to Excel sheet in C# UWP Windows 10 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779861/reading-and-writing-to-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp-uwp-windows-10-app)

Cheers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have to ask the company that offers that product.

Comment: "Price starts at $995 per developer"

Comment: So you mean to say after few days my UWP project will face problems in reading and writing excel files.

Answer (score 2):

Syncfusion libraries are commercial libraries and you can get pricing [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/). However, the whole suite of controls and libraries is available for free through the [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Hi Davis , Thanks for the reply but I want to know without community license will it work? I have already implemented this library in my project for reading and writing excel files . Its working fine till now , will I face any problem in future ? I don't want to take risk I have to deliver the product to the client I want to be 100% sure. Please clarify me on this.

Comment: @Ahmed: the library will work without any restrictions. Any entity using the library is required to acquire a license based on their eligibility, but the library will not stop working if there is no license.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, I really appreciate your support.